# What is the difference between displaying the information using a value attribute and just displaying the information between the two tags?

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and was studying forms when this question struck me. Let me illustrate with the following example:

When we use the label tags, the data between the opening and closing tags is printed as it is in our page. But when we use the nested option tags in datalist element, we have to provide a 'value' attribute whose value is the data that will be eventually printed on our page. What is the difference between the two approaches?

I tried reversing the roles, i.e., I used value attribute with label tag, with no data between the opening and closing tags (which removed the label altogether making me realize that value attribute doesn't work with label) and for option tag, I removed the value attribute and instead put the data in between the opening and closing tag (which worked as it is, making me realize that both ways are valid for option tag.)

Comment: value attribute belongs to input, textarea, select, etc.otherwise known as form controls. What sets form control apart from the other tags is that a user interacts with the user and the result of that interaction is saved in the value attribute. Upon a form being submitted, the form controls that have a name attribute will have their values sent to the server. The text even in an option will not be sent only a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we give inside the two tags is a fixed constant value and can't be changed by a user or the website too until we edit the code, while a value attribute is variable means that it can vary throughout the code.

So, let's say the user types in a username or something and we wanna save it and display it on the web-page then we don't already know when we write the code that what he's gonna type so in that case we can store it through PHP, JavaScript or something to the value attribute through which we can then print it onto the web-page!

Hope this was helpful :)
And yeah good-luck learning HTML and all it's very good way to start your journey! :)

Comment: I understand that value attribute is needed for variable or user defined data to store and send it via PHP, JavaScript, etc. But regarding the option tag, there is no way that this data can be user defined, so why do we need a value attribute here?

Comment: Actually in this case we as a client are given options predefined for the user to pick from but eventhough we do so.. The only way of JavaScript or PHP picking up the option selected by us is by adding it into the value attribute as then we tell HTML that what we have provided is meant to be picked up by the server or somethin' which isn't the case if you do the text between opening and closing tag try doin' some type of form with these options where the server displays the option selected we will see that it will throw an error if u didn't give it in the value attr.

Comment: Thx, for considering this a good answer. Hope u don't have this problem anymore :D